# Convert list of strings to store list of objects instead

Tags: python

Update:

I have asked a question re: conversion of list of strings to objects -- turns out the solution was CSV as mentioned in the comments below.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the list of strings. It wouldn't work because you also need the paramenters while converting. What are you trying to convert?

Comment: that looks like you made that list of strings ... you probably should not have made it into a list

Comment: yes, looks like csv

Comment: You should have made them dicts instead

Answer (score 1):

It seems the input is a csv, better to use csv module or pandas to make life easier.

```py
class Movie: 
    def __init__(self, name, category, description, price): 
        self.__name = name 
        self.category = category
        self.description = description 
        self.__price = price
        
l = ['Name,Category,Description,Price\n', 'titanic,romance,blabla,20\n', 'et,scifi,blabla,20\n']
l = list(map(lambda x: x.strip().split(','), l))

movie_list = list(map(lambda x: Movie(*x),l[1:]))
#[<__main__.Movie at 0x7fab3545b4f0>, <__main__.Movie at 0x7fab3545bb50>]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = list_of_strings[0].strip().split(',')
movies = []
for row in list_of_strings[1:]:
   movies.append(Movie(**dict(zip(keys,row.strip().split(",")))))
```

Is one way you could do it ...